# What is the remainder when $2001^{2014}$ is divided by $ 10^6$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the remainder when  $2001^{2014}$ is divided by $ 10^6$?

I have been searching for solution on the net but seems nothing has made me understand.

Comment: Have you tried anything _other than_ searching for a solution on the net?  (A very broad hint: do you know the binomial theorem?)

Comment: Hi yes, I've searched and tried, been struggling to understand binomial theorem.

Comment: If you can add some samples of what approaches you've tried taking, that would be useful.  (There's a very natural way of splitting the base 2001 that yields good results.)

Comment: To use th Binomial Theorem is a very good idea.

Comment: I have tried to understand this example http://gmatclub.com/forum/what-is-the-remainder-when-43-86-is-divided-by-134778.html. But I don't understand and confused until this part Now we know that raised to 6, the units digit is 9, the question says that 43 should be raised to 86 (which is equal to raised to 6, check our pattern). This means the units digit is 9.

Comment: That answer is a fairly confusing one - the one underneath it is much better (the one that writes 43 as 40+3) - though the case you have is a fairly different one.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
2001^{2014} = (1 + 2000)^{2014} = \\
\binom{2014}{0} + \binom{2014}{1} \cdot 2000 + 
\underbrace{\binom{2014}{2} \cdot 2000^2 + \binom{2014}{3} \cdot 2000^3 + \cdots}_
{\text{a multiple of }10^6}
$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the relevant binomial theorem: $(a+b)^n$ $= \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^k$ $= a^n+na^{n-1}b+\frac{n(n-1)}2a^{n-2}b^2+\ldots$

Now, $2001$ rather naturally splits up into $a=1$ and $b=2000$, so you can compute $(1+2000)^{2014}$; to find the remainder modulo (i.e. when divided by) $10^6$, you can find the remainder for each term in the sum separately and add them.  That's a lot of terms — $n=2014$, after all! — but if you start taking them one by one, you should see that as soon as you start getting terms of 'size' $b^2$ or above, the numbers are all divisible by $10^6$ and so have remainder $0$, so you only have to look at the first couple.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to apply the binomial theorem directly, you can start computing:

$2001^1=2001$

$2001^2=4004001\equiv 4001$

$2001^3 \equiv 4001\times 2001=8006001\equiv 6001$

$2001^4\equiv 6001\times 2001 = 12008001\equiv 8001$

Now that gives you a pattern you should be able to prove by induction.

Note also that there is a relatively quick computation of a power by repeated squaring, which doesn't show the pattern so directly (though it makes a very obvious pattern), but is an efficient computational method.

$2001^8 \equiv 8001^2\equiv 16001$

$2001^{16} \equiv 16001^2 \equiv 32001$

$2001^{32}\equiv 32001^2 \equiv 64001$

$\dots$

Comment: The moral is, if you can't see what to do, try something ... here there are some easy things to try, which point the way to a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

The binomials theorem states that $(a+b)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a^nb^{n-k}$. The symbol on the right means add the values of ${n\choose k}a^nb^{n-k}$ for $k=0$ up to $k=n$. Don't worry about $n\choose k$ just yet, for now it's just a number. Then we can write

$2001^{2014}=(2000+1)^{2014}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2014} {2014\choose k}2000^n1^{n-k}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2014} {2014\choose k}2000^n$

Notice that for $n\geq2,2000^n=2000^{n-2}2000^2=2000^{n-2} \cdot 2^2\cdot1000^2=2000^{n-2} \cdot 2^2\cdot10^6$, so it is divisible by $10^6$ when $n\geq2$. Therefore we only have to worry about the remainder of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1} {2014\choose k}2000^n={2014\choose0}+{2014\choose1}2000$, as the rest of the terms have no remainder.

Now to worry about those coefficients. Think of those coefficients as the number of ways you can "match" to make that number. For $(2000+1)^{2014}=(2000+1)(2000+1)...(2000+1)$, we need to find out how many ways you can "make" $2000^0$ and $2000^1$. For $2000^0$, obviously you can only multiply the $1$s together. So therefore ${2014\choose 0}=1$. For the $2000^1$ coefficient, you could take the $2000$ in the first bracket and multiply by the $1$s, or the second bracket, or the third... basically choose one bracket with $2000$ and the rest with $1$s. There are $2014$ brackets, so you can make $2014$ different $2000$s to add together. Therefore ${2014\choose1}=2014$. Plugging this in, the remainder of ${2014\choose0}+{2014\choose1}2000$ is the remainder of $1+2014\cdot2000=4028001$. The remainder of that divided by $10^6$ is $28001$. Therefore the remainder of $2001^{2014}$ when divided by $10^6$ is $28001$.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use techniques from cryptography. You need to compute $2001^{2004}mod10^6$ There is an algorithm called modular exponentiation. Say $a=2001, e=2004, n=10^6$. Then do:

$b=a$

for $i=\operatorname{BitLength}(e)-2$ downto $0$ do:

$b = b^2\times a^{\operatorname{Bit}(e,i)}\mod n$

return $b$

You need $O(\log_2e)$ calculations